# Is there a way to store commit comments (like on GitHub) directly inside Git repository?

Tags: git

GitHub or BitBucket support commenting on commits (GitHub even on the line level) but these comments are stored in their server-side database, not in the repository itself.

Is there a way / mechanism to store comments and possibly other metadata about commits directly inside the repository, so everyone who pulls from it gets it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use notes to store textual metadata on a commit:
http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html

Github used to [display them](https://github.com/blog/707-git-notes-display) in its interface, but not anymore since August 14, 2014

Comment: Nice! Yet another git feature I didn't know about.